# How to @import CSS in a React App?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have the following:

**Layout.jsx:**

```
....
import '../styles/core.css'
```

**core.css**

```
@import 'reset';
```

core.css works fine with just CSS but if I try to use an `@import` I get the following error:

```
07:58:15 web.1  | Error in ./src/styles/core.css
07:58:15 web.1  | Module not found: ./reset in /Users/x/sites/app/client/src/styles
07:58:15 web.1  | 
07:58:15 web.1  |  @ ./~/react-scripts/~/css-loader?importLoaders=1!./~/postcss-loader!./src/styles/core.css 3:10-155
07:58:15 web.1  | 
07:59:06 web.1  | Compiling...
07:59:07 web.1  | Failed to compile.
07:59:07 web.1  | 
07:59:07 web.1  | Error in ./src/styles/core.css
07:59:07 web.1  | Module not found: ./reset in /Users/x/sites/app/client/src/styles
07:59:07 web.1  | 
07:59:07 web.1  |  @ ./~/react-scripts/~/css-loader?importLoaders=1!./~/postcss-loader!./src/styles/core.css 3:10-155
```

How can I enable `@import` within my React app?

Thanks

Comment: @import is that css or less?

Comment: Isn't that just standard CSS? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import

Comment: @user1917603 can you post your webpack file as well?

Comment: That's a great question. I'm using the sample app here: https://github.com/timscott/react-devise-sample/tree/master/client --- it says in the readme that the app uses webpack: https://github.com/timscott/react-devise-sample/blob/master/client/README.md but I do not see a webpack config file. I'm a newbie to React so I must be missing something obvious... Can you help? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In case you are using webpack and you will probably need to use use ~ in the beginning of the path. So, if you want to import the following path node_modules/bootstrap/src/core.scss you would write something like

```
@import "~reset"
```

NOTE: 
It appears this isn't working for everybody. If your interpreter is based on libsass it should be working fine (checkout this). I've tested using @import on node-sass and it's working fine. Unfortunately this works and doesn't work on some ruby instances.

I've never used create react app, I use webpack here so if react app uses webpack as module bundler you should have this 2 dependencies in your project:

style-loader, css-loader and extract-text-webapack-plugin

Take a look at my snippet that are inside my webpack.config.js

```
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
 {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      use: 'css-loader',
    }),
  },
```